# dynamically adding and updating a div inside another div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a div inside this div that will populate my progress bar.

```
    <div class="progress">
    </div>
```

The javascript that I am trying to use is

```
function moveProgressBar(state) {
    let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("progress");
    let prog = state.count - 1;
    let value = ((prog / state.total) * 100) + '%';
    elem.innerHTML = '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style=value>';
}
```

The overall goal is to have a div and a sub-div that looks like this with the style value being populated by the moveProgressBar function.

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style=value>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery tag if your script is in javascript. EDIT: Why not to use <progress> ?

Comment: This is a really expensive way to do this. Use the `<progress>` element and update it's value in `moveProgressBar()` instead of get elements from the DOM on each state change. http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/

Answer (score 1):

The function `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, so what you want to do is `document.getElementsByClassName("progress")[0]` to get the first element.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an [HTML collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection#Usage_in_JavaScript) of all the elements with the provided class. You might want to perform the action on all such `.progress`es.

```
[].slice.call(elem).forEach(function (progBar) { ... } );

// [].slice.call to convert the HTML collection to a JavaScript array,
// upon which .forEach can be used.
//
// Other option would be to use a simple for loop to iterate through elem.
for(let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    let progBar = elem[i];
    ...
}
```

```js
function moveProgressBar(state) {
  let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("progress");

  let prog = state.count - 1;
  let value = ((prog / state.total) * 100) + '%';

  [].slice.call(elem).forEach(function(progressBar) {
    progressBar.innerHTML = '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:' + value + '">';
  });
}

// Sample run
var currCount = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  moveProgressBar({ count: (++currCount % 42), total: 42 });
}, 250);
```

```css
.progress { border: 1px #AAA solid; }
.progress-bar { height: 15px; background-color: #0E0; }
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>
```

Note, instead of creating a new `.progress-bar` element every time you  want to update the `.progress`es value, you might only want to change the existing `.progress-bar`'s width. You may also want to separately store the current value (`aria-valuenow`) separately, for each of the progress bars you define.